# Create Datasource in Code or get it via JNDI from Application Server

Tags: java, datasource, application-server

In a java application, If we want to use `javax.sql.DataSource` instead of `java.sql.DriverManager` to get connections, which approach would be better to create `DataSource` and WHY?

- Create `DataSource` in the application itself at the application startup time

or

- Configure `DataSource` in the application server and get it via `JNDI`

Comment: Either works. But if you let the server do it, the server manages it. If you create it in your application you have 100% control over how, when and where it is created and cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it actually depends upon the requirement. You can take this as a general rule.If you have multiple applications and sharing the same `DataSource`, then it can be a good choice to configure the `DataSource` in the server. Otherwise, if this is the only application uses the `DataSource`, then you can have it in the application level itself.